# Best timepicker for the blind/vision impaired users

Tags: android, accessibility, libraries, timepicker

I'm trying to make my app accessible to the blind users. The default android time picker dialog doesn't seem to be the best choice. Are there any time picker dialog libraries that work well with TalkBack?

Comment: You're building a native app, not an html app?

Comment: yes, native app